# Nested Ajax Call and JSON parsing

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Does nested ajax call interfere with JSON parsing?

I don't think so but I think I found something bizarre

SecondJob raises exception parsing ('unexpected character')

```
//-- Server - Both first.php and second.php
echo json_encode(array('result'=>'ok'));
//---------------

//-- Client (javascript, nested ajax calls) --
// (in class definition)
var self = this; // stores class instance
//
this.FirstJob = function (input) {
  $.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'first.php',
  // Here, response = "\n\n{\"result\": \"ok\"}"
  data: input, success: function(response) {
    var parsed = $.parseJSON(response);
    if(parsed.result==='ok') {
       var forSecond = 'some input';
       self.SecondJob(forSecond);
    }
  },
  error: function(x,s,e) {alert(...);}
}
this.SecondJob = function (input) {
  $.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'second.php',
    // Again, response = "{\"result\": \"ok\"}"
    // This seemingly valid string raises exception
    data: input, success: function(response) {
      var parsed = $.parseJSON(response);
      if(parsed.result==='ok') {
         var forThird = 'some input';
         self.ThirdJob(forThird);
      }
    },
    error: function(x, s, e) {alert(...);}
  )
}
this.ThirdJob = function (input) {
   // Can't go on
}
```

I went through checking common mistakes:

- There are no extra white spaces before/after php start/end.
- All PHP scripts are saved as Unicode texts.
- Key-Value pairs in the resultant string from PHP scripts are all wrapped inside double quotes (no single quotes)

Any possible scenario will help.

EDIT: The hosting is using php 5.2.x and can't be updated.

Comment: And what is the actual problem here I am not sure what you are trying to tell us is not working

Comment: SecondJob raises exception parsing seemingly valid JSON string

Comment: `alert(result);` and cross check once...

Comment: Already did with alert and debugger.

Comment: you are suing `json_encode ` in your php code?